# STUFF SQL Query in NHibernate, basically trying to replicate MySQLGroupConcat

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

Quick info on what I am trying to accomplish. I have some history tables and am joining the data into a single row for each history item. The issue I am having is trying to replicate a STUFF(query,1,1,'') in NHibernate. I have all my relationships setup and working and the query with just the joins works fine, just cant figure out how to implement the STUFF with a query into it.

This is the entire query:

```
SELECT h.*, u.FirstName, u.LastName, eh.*,
STUFF((
   SELECT CONCAT(c.Name, ' - ')
   FROM SubHistory sh
   LEFT JOIN Cust c ON c.CustID = sh.SubCustId
   WHERE h.Id = sh.HistoryId
   FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
) AS Subs
FROM History h
LEFT JOIN EmailHistory eh ON eh.HistoryId = h.Id
LEFT JOIN Usr u ON u.UsrID = h.UserId
```

The Result I need is (columns):

```
H.ID - H.ReportID - H.UserID - (Concatenated Subs) - u.FirstName - u.LastName - eh.Email
```

I can do this without the STUFF in Nhibernate like so:

```
IList<History> hist = session.QueryOver<History>(() => historyAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => historyAlias.User, () => usrAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => historyAlias.Email, () => emailAlias)
    .List();
```

I followed the tutorial here http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2014/08/15/queryover-series-part-7-using-sql-functions/ for creating the STUFF function, but I do not think it was created with the idea of using it the way I want to and I have been unable to successfully make it work.

So, my question can and how can I implement STUFF the way I want to? Or is there a better approach to getting the info I want?

Database Example for reference:

History Table

```
ID - ReportID - Name - UserID
```

SubHistory Table - (Can be many)

```
ID - HistoryID - SubInfo
```

UserTable

```
ID - FirstName - LastName
```

Cust Table

```
ID - CustInfo
```

EmailHistory Table - (Can only have one)

```
ID - HistoryID - Email
```

Comment: Is it really `stuff` the hard part? This function has nothing special. I am quite sure the actual road block is the `for xml` subquery you call inside it. How can this be translated as an entity query?

Comment: Well, if I understand what you are saying, that is basically my question. The sub-query in the "STUFF" is getting what I need. the concatenated columns of the sub-query. So, how can that be replicated in NHibernate. So, yeah, perhaps STUFF isn't the hard part, but part of what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine with enough tinkering, you can eventually get it to work with NHibernate calling `STUFF`, but it might take a very long time.  There might be a faster / easier solution: Create a view called `HistoryView` that essentially does the query you have at the top.  Then, create a new C# class also called `HistoryView` that has properties that correspond to your view's columns.  These `HistoryView` objects will be readonly, but it will accomplish the goal you're after.

Comment: Similarly, a [named SQL query](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html#querysql-namedqueries) could do the job easily.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up actually using a stored procedure call for this. I essentially did what Aron suggested with a View but as a stored proc instead, and created a new object to house the stored procedure returned rows.

How to call a SP in NHibernate:
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html#sp_query